# How to generate a random number from a truncated skewed normal distribution (Python)?

Tags: python, numpy, random, scipy

How can I generated a random number taken from a truncated skewed normal distribution, based on inputs of the lower/ upper bound, mean, and standard deviation?

Comment: i think what you are looking for is https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html

Comment: What have you tried? My approach would be to compute the lower and upper bounds of the distribution and than feeding those to a python random.randint().

Comment: @ChrisFowl. How?

Comment: A standard approach is to compute the CDF, and map the uniform distribution through that.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42552117/subclassing-of-scipy-stats-rv-continuous), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22447797/how-do-you-use-scipy-stats-rv-continuous) and [this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/1658/define-custom-probability-density-function-in-python) post might be helpful.